# D&D Dice simulator

Tags: powershell, random

I've come up with a rolling strategy where you roll 4d6 and reroll any duplicates. This results in a number between 10 and 18 this results in 14 being the most common and 10 and 18 the least common. To specify, you leave 1 of the duplicates and reroll the other(s). And I can't find this method on any dice rolling apps/online. I'm trying in PowerShell to run:

```
$A = Get-Random -Maximum 6 -Minimum 1
$B = Get-Random -Maximum 6 -Minimum 1
$C = Get-Random -Maximum 6 -Minimum 1
$D = Get-Random -Maximum 6 -Minimum 1

While ($A = $B) {
$B = Get-Random -Maximum 6 -Minimum 1
}
... 
...

$Stat = $A+$B+$C+$D
```

But $A and $B are always the same and $C and $D are always the same. Can anyone explain how Get-Random works and propose a solution for why my loop becomes infinite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of it as a sequence of individual dice rolls, repeated until you've seen 4 distinct values (which is exactly what it is), you can model it as:

```
function Roll-4d6 {
    # Use hashtable to keep track of face values
    $uniqueRolls = @{}

    # Keep rolling until we've seen 4 distinct faces
    while($uniqueRolls.Count -lt 4){
        # Roll the dice, make note of unique face value
        $roll = 1..6 |Get-Random
        $uniqueRolls[$roll] = $roll
    }

    # Calculate and return sum
    return $uniqueRolls.Values |Measure-Object -Sum |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
}
```

Executing it 10K times will reveal the true distribution of re-rolling 4d6 on duplicates (not quite what you seem to be expecting):

```
1..10000 |ForEach-Object {
  Roll-4d6
} |Group-Object -NoElement |Sort Name

# outputs something along the lines of
Count Name
----- ----
  686 10
  650 11
 1334 12
 1323 13
 2044 14
 1314 15
 1348 16
  664 17
  637 18
```

The simple explanation being that there's only *one* combination of rolls that produce each of 10 (`1,2,3,4`), 11 (`1,2,3,5`), 17 (`2,4,5,6`) and 18 (`3,4,5,6`).

To mimic the same distribution with a single sampling, you would do:

```
$roll = 10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 18 |Get-Random
```

---

#### Note on `-Maximum`

Beware that `Get-Random`'s `-Maximum` parameter is an exclusionary, so for a 6-faced dice you'll want `Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 7`

Comment: So, 
```10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18 | Get-Random```
would be more accurate for what I'd like to do, if not in the spirit of it...

Comment: No, that would not be accurate, I've added an example of how to do it in a single statement to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for arbitrary number of dice, rerolling until unique and returning an array.

```
function RollDice {
    param (
        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)][parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)][int]$Amount,
        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)][Alias('d')][int]$Sides
    )
    if ($Amount -gt $Sides) {
        throw "Invalid parameter - The number of sides ($Sides) must be greater than the number of dice thrown ($Amount)"
    }

    [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]$Results = @()

    for ($DiceNum = 1; $DiceNum -le $Amount; $DiceNum++) {
        while (!([int]$Roll) -or $Roll -in $Results) {
            $Roll = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum ($Sides + 1)  #Maximum pulls a number less than, not equal. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random
        }
        $Results += $Roll
    }
    
    Return $Results
}

RollDice 4 -d 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that uses lists and does not require rerolling duplicates:

```
Function Roll {

    # Die face values
    $roll = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]@(1..6)
    # Perform the required number of rolls
    $values = 1..4 | Foreach-Object { 
        # Random roll
        $r = Get-Random -InputObject $roll
        # Remove rolled value from list to prevent duplicates
        [void]$roll.Remove($r)
        # return roll
        $r
    }
    # Sum rolls
    ($values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
}

# Execute the rolls
Roll

# Output
16
```